# How to use SVG images in Adaptive Cards

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to use SVG image to display image in Adaptive Cards, But it is not rendering. I am configuring  like below

```
{
    "type": "Image",
    "url":  "MY_SVG_IMAGE_URL_PATH",
    "size": "small"
}
```

But it is not rendering on the screen (web channel)

Comment: Hi Varad! Which channel are you using? Some channels do not allow SVG images.

Comment: What does actual value of `"MY_SVG_IMAGE_URL_PATH"` look like?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I am using Webchat channel.

Comment: @FeiHan : I got the issue resolved by your answer below, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to use SVG image to display image in Adaptive Cards, But it is not rendering.

I suspect that you provided an invalid/unsupported URL of your SVG image, which cause the image is not readering in webchat channel.

To display SVG image in Adaptive Cards, you can refer to the following sample code that works for me.

```
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();

card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = "Show SVG Images",
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder
});

//use the entire SVG syntax
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveImage()
{
    Type = "Image",
    UrlString = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' width='100' height='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='green' stroke-width='4' fill='yellow' />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>",
    Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Small
});

//convert SVG into Base64 encoding
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveImage()
{
    Type = "Image",
    UrlString = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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",
    Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Small
});

replymes.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
    Content = card,
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Name = "Card"
});

// return our reply to the user
await context.PostAsync(replymes);
```

*Test result:*

[image]

Comment: SVG doesn't render inside a Teams adaptive card.